# How to show a value with query_set in a serializer using Django rest framework?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am making an API and want to list all choices of a model for who use it.

```py
# -------------------------------------------------------------
#                   Image category serializer
# -------------------------------------------------------------


class ImageCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    #category = CategorySerializer()
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source="category.category",
        many=True,
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
    )
    image = serializers.IntegerField(source="image.id")
    
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = ImageCategory


# -------------------------------------------------------------
#                           Category
# -------------------------------------------------------------


class Category(models.Model):
    """
    This model define a category

    Args:
        category (datetime): creation date
        created_at (str): description of the image
    """


    class CategoryChoice(models.TextChoices):
        """
        This inner class define our choices for several categories
    
        Attributes:
            VIDEOGAMES tuple(str): Choice for videogames.
            ANIME tuple(str): Choice for anime.
            MUSIC tuple(str): Choice for music.
            CARTOONS tuple(str): Choice for cartoons.
        """
        
        VIDEOGAMES = ('VIDEOGAMES', 'Videogames')
        ANIME = ('ANIME', 'Anime')
        MUSIC = ('MUSIC', 'Music')
        CARTOONS = ('CARTOONS', 'Cartoons')


    category = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CategoryChoice.choices, null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is shown
[image]

I want to replace the "Category object('number')" options by the choices of Category model(VIDEOGAMES, ANIME, MUSIC and CARTOONS).

Comment: Add a `__str__` method to your Category model to change the display in a select field. This question is about the rest framework, where is this form even shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried implementing `__str__` in your model?

```
def __str__(self):
   /*return what you want to display */
```